# How can I split dataset into several dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, split

I have a dataset which has thousand of rows with a column 'state' and some other columns.

A sample dataset

[image: sample dataset]

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'State':['C','C','C','R','R','D','D','R','C','C','R','D','R','C','R','D','R'],
        'Qd': [3, 2, 1, 0,2,2,5,7,9,7,14,34,12,10,11,14,15], 
        
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

The 'State' column has a loop type input value like 'C,R,D,R' and then again 'C,R,D,R'. I want to split the dataset into several dataframe like

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

df3

[image]

Each dataframe will contain one complete loop from the State Column. How to do this?

I am thinking to create a list of dataframe and use a for loop to store each loop value in each dataframe.

Comment: Now it's clear but can you copy/paste your sample dataset as plain text, please?

Comment: It's not advised to link to datasets, but rather to put a minimal reproducible sample within the question.

Comment: Please read [ask] *before* asking...

Comment: I have added the dataset as plain text now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following lines assume **items** containing set of periodic state values. **data0** is a panda data frame prior to any splitting process. All state values are following orders as declared in the list **items**.

```
import pandas as pd

items=['C','R','D','R']
pattern_length=len(items)
count=0
current_state=data0.State[0]

dataframes=list()
temp_df=pd.DataFrame()
df_count=0

for index, row in data0.iterrows():
  if current_state!=row.State[0]:
    count=count+1
    current_state=row.State[0]

    if count==pattern_length:
      dataframes.append(temp_df)
      temp_df=pd.DataFrame()
      count=0
      df_count=df_count+1

  temp_df=temp_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
dataframes.append(temp_df)
df_count=df_count+1
```

Note that, **dataframes[0]**,**dataframes[1]** and so on, are the data frames after the split. Also, **df_count** should give you total numbers of data frames created.